# Creating a table using postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was asked to create a table using PostgreSQL and use the following information:

> The properties table should consist of: property_id (this should be
>   the primary key as well as a unique number that increments
>   automatically) name number of units owner_id (this should have the
>   constraint NOT NULL) There should be also be a foreign key that
>   references the owners table

### I wrote the following

```
apartmentlab=# CREATE TABLE properties (
apartmentlab(# PRIMARY KEY property_id SERIAL,
apartmentlab(# name TEXT,
apartmentlab(# num_of_units numeric,
apartmentlab(# FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners (owner_id) NOT NULL
apartmentlab(# );
```

---

and I'm getting the following message:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "property_id" LINE 2: PRIMARY KEY
>   property_id SERIAL,

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the property_id and my syntax. I've looked at the documentation and this looks to be correct.

Comment: The documentation does not show `primary key` at the beginning of a a column definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PRIMARY KEY` clause comes after the data type:

```
CREATE TABLE properties (
    property_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    num_of_units numeric,
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners (owner_id) NOT NULL
);
```

Also note your mistake in the foreign key definition. You probably need to define the field `owner_id`, with the same data type as that in the table being referenced, in your table as well.